# TypeError when converting Pandas to Spark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

So I have looked up this question on here but previous solutions have not worked for me. I have a DataFrame in this format

```
mdf.head()
    dbn       boro       bus
0   17K548  Brooklyn    B41, B43, B44-SBS, B45, B48, B49, B69
1   09X543  Bronx       Bx13, Bx15, Bx17, Bx21, Bx35, Bx4, Bx41, Bx4A,...
4   28Q680  Queens      Q25, Q46, Q65
6   14K474  Brooklyn    B24, B43, B48, B60, Q54, Q59
```

There are a couple more columns but I have excluded them (subway lines and test scores). When I try to convert this DataFrame into a Spark DataFrame I am given an error which is this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-1721be5c2987> in <module>()
----> 1 sparkdf = sqlc.createDataFrame(mdf)

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
    423             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
    424         else:
--> 425             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)
    426         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    427         jdf = self._ssql_ctx.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    339 
    340         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 341             struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data)
    342             if isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
    343                 for i, name in enumerate(schema):

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in _inferSchemaFromList(self, data)
    239             warnings.warn("inferring schema from dict is deprecated,"
    240                           "please use pyspark.sql.Row instead")
--> 241         schema = reduce(_merge_type, map(_infer_schema, data))
    242         if _has_nulltype(schema):
    243             raise ValueError("Some of types cannot be determined after inferring")

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in _merge_type(a, b)
    860         nfs = dict((f.name, f.dataType) for f in b.fields)
    861         fields = [StructField(f.name, _merge_type(f.dataType, nfs.get(f.name, NullType())))
--> 862                   for f in a.fields]
    863         names = set([f.name for f in fields])
    864         for n in nfs:

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in _merge_type(a, b)
    854     elif type(a) is not type(b):
    855         # TODO: type cast (such as int -> long)
--> 856         raise TypeError("Can not merge type %s and %s" % (type(a), type(b)))
    857 
    858     # same type

TypeError: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>
```

From what I have read this might be a problem with the headers being treated as data. It is my understanding you can't remove the headers from a DataFrame so how would I proceed with solving this error and converting this DataFrame into a Spark one?

Edit: Here is the code for how I created the Pandas DF and worked my way around the problem.

```
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('hsdir.csv', encoding = 'utf_8_sig'))
df = df[['dbn', 'boro', 'bus', 'subway', 'total_students']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('sat_r.csv', encoding = 'utf_8_sig'))
df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'Num of SAT Test Takers': 'num_test_takers', 'SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score': 'read_avg', 'SAT Math Avg. Score' : 'math_avg', 'SAT Writing Avg. Score' : 'write_avg'})
mdf = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on = 'dbn', right_on = 'DBN', how = 'left')
mdf = mdf[pd.notnull(mdf['DBN'])]
mdf.to_csv('merged.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
ndf = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("merged.csv")
```

The last line of this code, loading it from my local machine ended up allowing me to convert the CSV properly to a Data Frame however my question still remains. Why did it not work in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use reflection to infer the schema from an RDD of `Row` objects, e.g.,

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
mdfRows = mdf.map(lambda p: Row(dbn=p[0], boro=p[1], bus=p[2]))
dfOut = sqlContext.createDataFrame(mdfRows)
```

Does that achieve the desired result?

Comment: I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`

Comment: Oh.  `mdf` is a pandas DataFrame?  I assumed wrongly that it was a Spark RDD.  Do you need to use pandas?  Or can you create a Spark RDD and then convert it to a Spark DataFrame as above?

Comment: So this is the issue I face. If I load it as an RDD using `com.databricks.spark.csv` to read it as a CSV, it completely disregards the dbn column and moves everything one column to the left. I'm not sure how to avoid this issue so I loaded it through Pandas `read_csv` which preserved the formatting of the original CSV.

Comment: Is what you're saying is that you tried `spark.read.csv("/path/to/file.csv", header=True)`, and that did not work?

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure what the issue is...  I have made a pandas DataFrame from the sample data you gave and executed `sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(df)` without problem.  I've also made a CSV file from the sample data and ran `sparkDF = spark.read.csv("sample.csv", header=True)`, also without issue.  Maybe you could include in your question a little about how you created the pandas DataFrame?

Comment: I used the spark-cdv package since I'm using Spark 1.6.2 (thats the latest version available on HomeBrew). Should I update to 2.0 since I know that they inlined the `read.csv` directly into the program? The problem is I am assuming the CSV has encoded characters and/or trailing/leading whitespace. I'll update the post with how I created the pandas frame. I also was able to get around the problem by saving it on my local machine with proper encoding, which is probably not good practice for Apache Spark.

Comment: I upgraded my spark and `spark.read.csv` worked like a charm. I was able to bypass Pandas and avoid this whole issue. Much thanks!

Comment: No problem, Dmitry!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and was able to track it down to a single entry which had a value of length 0 (or empty). The `_inferScheme` command runs on each row of the dataframe and determines the types. By default assumption is that the empty value is a Double while the other is a String. These two types cannot be merged by the `_merge_type` command. The issue has been filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18178, but the best way around is probably supplying a schema to the `createDataFrame` command.

The code below reproduces the problem in PySpark 2.0

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
test_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(',Scan Options\n15,SAT2\n16,\n'))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(test_df).registerTempTable('Test')
o_qry = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Test LIMIT 1")
o_qry.first()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well:

```
def create_spark_dataframe(file_name):
   """
   will return the spark dataframe input pandas dataframe
   """
   pandas_data_frame = pd.read_csv(file_name, converters= {"PRODUCT": str})
   for col in pandas_data_frame.columns:
   if ((pandas_data_frame[col].dtypes != np.int64) & 
      (pandas_data_frame[col].dtypes != np.float64)):
    pandas_data_frame[col] = pandas_data_frame[col].fillna('')

   spark_data_frame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_data_frame)
   return spark_data_frame
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is pandas default `np.nan`(Not a number) value for empty string, which creates a confusion in Schema while converting to spark.df.

Basic approach is convert np.nan to None, which will enable it to work

Unfortunately, pandas does not let you fillna with None. As, np.nan doesn't follow self equality condition, you can do this nifty trick.

```
new_series = new_series.apply(lambda x: None if x != x else x)
```

Then, `display(sqlContext.createDataFrame(new_df_1))` would work fine

Comment: I would be glad if anyone could suggest me a direct way to convert nan to None

Comment: I filled NaN with 0s and it didn't solve the error.

Comment: @LePuppy, what is the datatype of your column, also, check my updated solution, it's independent of datatype of a column and should work

Comment: I have string and double types. I figured out converting all to string enabled me to create the spark dataframe. Then, I still can use cast to convert column types.

Comment: @LePuppy that's just too much work, isn't this one takes care of all of that in more systematic manner

Comment: I get a ValuError 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.' Indeed your lambda function apply to each Series then x != x raises this error

Comment: am i correct in assuming, you are running apply on pd.DataFrame and not pd.Series. use apply or applymap appropriately

Comment: Yes I am. But isn't that what your code does ? I'm lost

Comment: In my code, it is a pandas Series, you need to get ur Dataframe to series level using new_df_1['column_name'].apply(func)

Comment: Of course, I just assumed new_df_1 was a dataframe. You should consider changing its name to something closer than a Series

Comment: And still, it didn't solve my issue. Maybe we're talking about two different things without knowing